# AngularJS Tabs generating dynamic content

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and javascript. I have a text box in the dynamically generated angular js tabs. I dont want the value to refresh every time I click on the other tabs. Is static tabs the only option or is there a work around? Just an example fiddle.

[`Js Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/kubh1mst/vLahv26w/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your input use a different ng-model for your 3 templates.

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="myModel1">
```

so you will be able to change tabs and keeping input.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vLahv26w/11/
There was a problem if you use the model directly in the scope. you have to use an object that will contains the value in order to keep the reference on it